# Drawing Binary Tree from inorder and preorder

Tags: binary-tree

In-order traversal: 24,17,32,18,51,11,26,39,43
Pre-order traversal: 11,32,24,17,51,18,43,26,39

The question asked to find which nodes belong on the right subtree of the root node. I am having trouble constructing the tree based on the 2 traversal methods..

Would greatly appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Have a look at [this blog post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/).

Comment: You can't, in general, determine the full tree from just one type of traversal.  And your tree does not produce the pre-order traversal you started with.

Comment: I think you confuse binary tree with binary **search** tree. A search tree has an additional condition `left < root < right` which a binary tree does not have.

Comment: Oh crap you're right I did not read the question clearly... Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Ok the nodes which belong to the right subtree of the root node would be 43, 26, 39. Is this correct?

Comment: Originally you determined that the root was 11; do you still believe that, and if not, what do you think the root is now?

Comment: I still think root is 11 since pre order starts with root

Comment: Why is this tagged with `binary-search` and `binary-search-tree`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tree that is defined by those two traversals is:

```
        __ 11 __
       /        \
   _ 32 _        43
  /      \      /
24        51  26
  \      /      \
   17  18        39
```

The procedure to build this, is described in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213069/how-to-build-a-binary-tree-from-preorder-and-inorder-traversals)